# Why does my char array print random trailing characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string, random, character

I'm a complete novice to programming and I really need your help. After calling AddS more than once, and then calling ListS to display everything stored in struct subject *a, the *first* print of the struct member **tag** is printed only up to 12 characters correct, followed by random trailing characters. On the next iteration of the loop, **tag** is printed with all characters correct. I've tried lowering the size of tag and it seems that it removed the trailing characters. What exactly is happening here?

```
struct store
{
    char call[7], tag[450];
    int units;
};

void AddS(struct store *a, int *n)
{
    char ecode[8], etags[450];
    int f, error = 0;
    struct store *tempptr;

    scanf("%s", ecode);
    scanf("%d", &f);
    scanf("%s", etags); 

    NameLimit(ecode);
    if(Initial(ecode) && Occurrence(ecode, a, *n))
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
        error++;
    }

    if(!error)
    {
        if(*n)
        {       
            tempptr = realloc(a, *n + 1);
            a = tempptr;
        }

        if(tempptr || !*n)
        {
            strcpy((a + *subctr) -> call, ecode);
            (a + *n) -> units = f;

            if (etags[0] == '.')
                (a + *n) -> tag[0] = '\0';
            else
                strcpy((a + *n) -> tag, etags); 

            printf("%s added.\n", ecode);
            *n = *n + 1;
        }
        else if(tempptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("No space.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    }       
}

void ListS(struct store *a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s %d %s\n", (a + i) -> call, (a + i) -> units, (a + i) -> tag);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output too?

Comment: `char code[7];` smaller than `char ecode[8]`

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `realloc()` is a *byte size* for the new allocation.

There's not enough code shown to be sure, but this:

```
tempptr = realloc(a, *subctr + 1);
```

should *very probably* be

```
tempptr = realloc(a, (*subctr + 1) * sizeof *a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The member `char code[7]` defined in the structure `struct subject` is less than `char ecode[8]` that you have defined inside your `AddS()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using scanf to read input I would recommend you to use fgets and sscanf. Scanf is considered to be rather unsafe.